# Quick way to debug my app using Production environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

By default, ASP.NET Core applications run in the *Development* environment when running within Visual Studio. I need to debug the *Production* environment. What is the easiest way to switch between environments?

I see the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is being set under my project properties. But I don't understand why it is set in two places: once for my project and once for IIS Express.

Do I need to edit both of these? Is it possible to do this from code.

I may want to switch back and forth, and I have to be sure to restore it when I'm done, so I'm looking for a simple way to set this.

Comment: "I see the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is being set under my project properties." do you mean the launchSettings.json file? By default, this file has two configurations, one for hosting with IIS (express) and one for stand-alone with console. You can add more configurations as needed.

Comment: @gunr2171: I mean in the project properties window.

Comment: Where in the project properties window? Which runtime is your app targeting?

Comment: It depends, if you are locally running a website, webservice, etc. and said component is running in IIS. Then you need to alter the IIS settings. 
If it isn't, then only the other option is required to be altered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean in the project properties window.

Those are launch profiles:

[image]

And they are controlled by `launchSettings.json` located in `Properties` folder of the project (see [Development and launchSettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson)). The `launchSettings.json` file:

- Is only used on the local development machine.
- Is not deployed.
- Contains profile settings.

You have two profiles, one launches app under IIS Express and the other uses [Kestrel web server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-7.0). You can the one you want. Potentially the easiest option to run and debug locally would be setting `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `Production` and editing `appsettings.json` file to contain production values (or `appsettings.Production.json` so you don't need to pollute your main one, see [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)).

Comment: I found if I just changed it to `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Developmentx`, then it defaults to production. I only need to set this for IIS Express (not for my project). Also, I didn't need to make any changes to *appsettings.json*.